# The instruction at “0x7c910a19” referenced memory at “oxffffffff”. The memory could not be “read”

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sql, oracle, vbscript

I have a small issue, I receive the following error before the .vbs terminates. I don't know why this error is thrown. Below is the process of the .vbs file:

```
Call ImportTransactions()
Call UpdateTransactions()

Function ImportTransactions()

  Dim objConnection, objCommand, objRecordset, strOracle
  Dim strSQL, objRecordsetInsert

  Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConnection.Open "DSN=*****;UID=*****;PWD==*****;"
  Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  strOracle = "SELECT query here from Oracle database"

  objCommand.CommandText = strOracle
  objCommand.CommandType = 1
  objCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
  Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
  objRecordset.cursorType = 0
  objRecordset.cursorlocation = 3  
  objRecordset.Open objCommand, , 1, 3

  If objRecordset.EOF = False Then
    Do Until objRecordset.EOF = True        
      strSQL = "INSERT query here into SQL database" 
      strSQL = Query(strSQL)
      Call RunSQL(strSQL, objRecordsetInsert, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword)
      objRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop
  End If

  objRecordset.Close()
  Set objRecordset = Nothing
  Set objRecordsetInsert = Nothing

End Function

Function UpdateTransactions()

  Dim strSQLUpdateVAT, strSQLUpdateCodes
  Dim objRecordsetVAT, objRecordsetUpdateCodes

  strSQLUpdateVAT = "UPDATE query here SET [value:costing output] = ([value:costing output] * -1)"
  Call RunSQL(strSQLUpdateVAT, objRecordsetVAT, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword) 

  strSQLUpdateCodes = "UPDATE query here SET [value:costing output] = ([value:costing output] * -1) different WHERE clause"
  Call RunSQL(strSQLUpdateCodes, objRecordsetUpdateCodes, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword)                 

  Set objRecordsetVAT = Nothing
  Set objRecordsetUpdateCodes = Nothing

End Function
```

It does both the import and update and seems to throw this error after. If I comment out the ImportTransactions it doesnt throw a error, however I have produced similar code for another vbs file and this does not throw any errors

Thanks in advance for any help,

Clare